# Images from Azure blob containers not displaying in ListView on ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, azure, listview, azure-blob-storage

I am loading a `Listview` from a sql server database. Rows contain a `blob ID`. I construct the `blob ID`s from the base url of the blob container then attempt to display the images. Nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
protected void PhotosListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var itm = e.Item;
    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)itm.FindControl("itemImageButton");
    Label TNlbl = (Label)itm.FindControl("BlobPhotoIDLabel");
    string blobContainerId = (string)Session["BlobContId"];
    string imgUrl = blobClient.StorageUri.PrimaryUri + blobContainerId.ToLower() + "/" + TNlbl.Text;
    imgBtn.ResolveClientUrl(imgUrl);
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<td runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="itemImageButton" runat="server" 
                            CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" 
                            Width="180" Height="120"
                            OnCommand="itemImageButton_Command"/>
                <br />PhotoId:
                <asp:Label ID="PhotoIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhotoId") %>' />
                <br />PhotoTitle:
                <asp:Label ID="PhotoTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhotoTitle") %>' />
        // etc
```

The heck of it is similar code on another page works fine. What am I missing? I have tried it also in the data binding and data bound events. The title and other data from the database are displaying okay. Blob urls constructed appear valid.

Comment: Please ensure that the container in which the images are stored doesn't have `Private` ACL. It should either be `Blob` or `Container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blob urls constructed appear valid.

You could try to put he blob url in the browser to check if the image is available.

If you could not view it in the browser, then as Gaurav said, check your container's `Public Access Level`. It should be `Blob` or `Container` instead of `Private(no anonymous access)`.

If the url is valid, use the following code to display image:

```
Url=imgBtn.ResolveClientUrl(imgUrl); //Gets a URL that can be used by the browser.
imgBtn.imageUrl(Url);
```

For more details about `ResolveClientUrl`, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: That worked with one small change: imgBtn.ImageUrl = url;